# Accessing a png from inside a JAR

Tags: java, image, jar

Currently I have a compiled JAR file as follows:

```
RunMe.jar  
-GUIFile.class  
-Main.class  
-Notify.class  
-resources  
--sprites  
---myimg.png  
-com  
--random  
---package  
----MakeNotify.class
```

Please explain to me how to access the PNG myimg.png inside `MakeNotify.java`

Thanks for all the advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This depends, but generally, you want to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` depending on how you want to read it.

Something like...

```
 BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/sprites/myimg.png"));
```

for example...

Comment: Also, check that the resource has been compiled into your war/jar/ear. Maven will ensure this, but your project directory structure does not look like a Maven project.

Comment: @kiwiron Since the root was `RunMe.jar` I had assumed that this was the packaged output

Comment: Correct, this is the packaged output. The files are all inside the jar file.

Comment: When I use getResourceAsStream or getResource :  
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!  
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)

Comment: If you're getting a `null` input, then the images aren't where you think they are or aren't named the way you think they are (the path is case sensitive)